# Ubuntu 14.04 Duplicate source.list error

Tags: duplicates, ubuntu-14.04, datastax

When i try to update my Ubuntu 14.04 which also hosts a cassandra database, i get the following error:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/community/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.datastax.com_community_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/community/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.datastax.com_community_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

When i check the /etc/apt/source.list file, these deb packages are actualy not even there. How can i fix this issue? Even runnung sudo apt-get update for the second time produces the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

you should look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder for any custom apt repos.

Comment: I looked there, but i do not see any apt repos related datastax.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `cassandra.sources.list` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

You can remove the entries using:

```
sudo sort -u /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```